# Remove methode and Node

Tags: java

I created a private Node remove method but I keep getting error which said the method must return Node type. can someone help me?

```
private Node remove(Node n){

    Node current = first;
    Node pre=null;

    w
    }
}
```

Comment: You must return a Node since the return type is Node.

Comment: Hint: What happens when `current != null` at the end of the method? What does the method return in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't cover the case when you've found the node to remove

```
private Node remove(Node n){
    Node current = first;

    Node pre=null;

    while(current!=null && !current.equals(n)){

        pre=current;

        current=current.next;

    }

if(current==null){

    return null;

} else {
  //found the node to remove. Connect the pre with the next node, and 
  //return the current node
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of your method is of type **Node**

```
    private Node remove(Node n)
```

If you don't want to return anything, change the return type to **void**
else return the current node as suggested.

```
    if(current==null){
       return null;
    } else {
       pre.next = current.next;
       return current; // the node which was remove
    }
```